# Help checking the proof that $\int_a^bf(x)>0$ for a conti. function that a point greater than $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

I have a question: Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be continuous and $\forall x,~f(x)\geq 0$. Suppose $f(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0\in[a,b]$, I was asked to prove that $\int_a^bf(x)>0$. I want someone help me to check if my proof is wrong or having a weak point. And I even want to know whether my proof is too silly or redundant, or could be better.

**My attempt:** I have already proved the fact that $\int_a^bf(x)\ge 0$ (skipped). So I only need to show that $\int_a^bf(x)>0$.

Suppose $\int_a^bf(x)=0$.

Since $f$ is continous at $x_0$, by the definition of continuity, there exists $δ>0$ such that $∀x\in[a,b],~|x-x_0|<δ\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$.

Choose $δ'=\frac{δ}{2}$, then $∀x\in[a,b],~|x-x_0|≤δ'\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$.

Since $\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
&|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{f(x_0)}{2}\\
\Rightarrow ~&-\frac{f(x_0)}{2}<f(x)-f(x_0)<\frac{f(x_0)}{2}\\
\Rightarrow ~&-\frac{f(x_0)}{2}+f(x_0)<f(x)\\
\Rightarrow ~&\frac{f(x_0)}{2}<f(x)\\
\end{alignedat}$,

we have $∀x\in[a,b],~|x-x_0|≤δ'\Rightarrow f(x)>\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$.

Since $f(x_0)δ'>0$, apply this positive number to the definition of $\int_a^bf(x)=0$, we deduce that there exists $\eta>0$ such that:

$∀P:\text{partition of }[a,b],~∀T:\text{sample set of }P,~\|P\|<\eta\Rightarrow |R(P,T)-0|=|R(P,T)|<f(x_0)δ'$

Let $P$ be any partition so that $\|P\|<\eta$ and $x_0-δ',~x_0+δ'\in P$. Let $T$ be any sample set of $P$.

Let $P'\subseteq P$ and $P'=\{x_0-δ'=y_0,y_1,~y_2,~y_3,~\cdots,~x_0+δ'=y_n\}$.

Then $\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}R(P,T)&≥R(P',T)~~~(\text{Because }∀x,~f(x)≥0)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(\xi_i)\Delta y_i>\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{f(x_0)}{2}\Delta y_i=\frac{f(x_0)}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\Delta y_i=\frac{f(x_0)}{2}2δ'=f(x_0)δ'\end{alignedat}$.

On the other hand, by the definition of integral, $|R(P,T)|<f(x_0)δ'$.
$∴$ We have deduce a contradition.

Comment: Doing this directly from definition seems redundant. I'd use the first part of your proof, scrap the other one, and use the fact that $f(x)\geq g(x) \implies \int_a^b f(x)\text{dx}\geq \int_a^b g(x)\text{dx}$

Comment: @Jakobian Not quite understand, can you post an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Let $g(x)$ be $f(x_0)/2$ for the correct interval, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: You may use $\int_c^d f≥ \int_c^dg $ whenever $[C,d]\subseteq[a,b]$ and $f≥g $ in $[C,d]$ where both $f,g$ are integrable in $[a,b]$ after the line "we have $∀x\in[a,b],~|x-x_0|≤δ'\Rightarrow f(x)>\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$ ". That is $c=x_0-\delta' ,d=x_0+\delta' ,g=f(x_0)/2 \ on [C,d]$

Comment: Is it? $\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
\int_a^bf(x)dx&=\int_a^{x_0-δ'}f(x)dx+\int_{x_0-δ'}^{x_0+δ'}f(x)dx+\int_{x_0+δ'}^bf(x)dx≥\int_{x_0-δ'}^{x_0+δ'}f(x)dx\\
&≥\int_{x_0-δ'}^{x_0+δ'}\frac{f(x_0)}{2}dx=\frac{f(x_0)}{2}2δ'=f(x_0)δ'>0
\end{alignedat}$.

Comment: This proof is correct, the "proof" in the question is not O.K.

Comment: @Ahmad Besides my proofs' being redundant, can you tell me which part is logical wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, if $f(x) > 0$ then there exists $\varepsilon >  0$ so that $f$ is at a strictly positive distance $d$ from zero in $[x- \varepsilon, x+ \varepsilon] \subset [a,b]$. Thus,

$$
\int_a^bf(t)dt = \int_a^{x-\varepsilon}f(t)dt + \int_{x - \varepsilon}^{x + \varepsilon}f(t)dt + \int_{x + \varepsilon}^bf(t)dt \geq \int_{x - \varepsilon}^{x + \varepsilon}f(t)dt \geq d2\varepsilon > 0.
$$

If the first claim is not clear, suppose that $f(x) > 0$ but the claim is false: now for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it cannot be that $f(x- \frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n})$ is at positive distance of $0$ and so in particular, some point $x_n \in (x- \frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n})$ must verify $f(x_n) < \frac{1}{n}$. Thus, $x_n \to x$ and so $0 < f(x) = \lim_n f(x_n) \leq \lim_n \frac{1}{n} = 0$ which is absurd.

I think this sums up your argument, without having to handle partitions.